# Linear-mixed effect for single timepoint/modeling a single timepoint with random effects?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, modeling, linear-model, random-effects-model

I am trying to figure out how best to model advantage between conditions using the difference in mean accuracies (initially coded as 0 and 1). Not included is an Accuracy column with either 0s and 1s for Item-level performance. The data is also formatted for a mixed-effect model to start with, so in actuality it is, let's say, 70 rows of P1 for all 70 Items. This means that Accuracy-Condition0 (A-C0), Accuracy-Condition1 (A-C1), and Condition Advantage (CA) are all the same down the 70 rows (though Accuracy is of course changing by Item).

The data look something like this:

| Participant ID | Accuracy-Condition 0 | Accuracy-Condition 1 | Condition Advantage (A-C0 minus A-C1) | Individual-specific covariates | Item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | .42 | .20 | .22 | xx | Item1 |
| P2 | .92 | .78 | .14 | xx | Item2 |
| P3 | .55 | .45 | .10 | xx | Item3 |
| P4 | .65 | .44 | .19 | xx | Item4 |

Items also have some Item-specific information, motivating Item as a random effect.

| Item | ItemCondition | ItemDifficulty | ItemFrequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | 0 | 4 | 13.22 |
| Item2 | 1 | 50 | 9.42 |
| Item3 | 0 | 13 | 23.11 |
| Item4 | 1 | 40 | 4.01 |

I have already fit glmer models to help explain what is influencing performance on (Item) Condition 0 and (Item) Condition 1 separately, with the individual-specific covariates as fixed effects, Participant ID and Item as random effects, and Accuracy as the DV.

Now I would like to reconcile these by examining Condition Advantage, using individual-specific covariates to examine the influences on CA. Much of the literature surrounding this idea runs an ANOVA between conditions with an effect size calculations on the Condition Advantage, though this would exclude all of the individual-specific factors I am interested in.

So, since we have individual-specific data, I was wondering how to fit a linear-mixed model (specifically to maintain Participant ID and Item as random effects) on these data -- or if someone could help in thinking through how to change the format -- since lmer is throwing up huge errors due to the fact, I suspect, that there is no change along the 70 rows in the DV. Right now my formula looks like this:

```
mod1 <- lmer(CondAdv ~ ItemFrequency + PChar1 + 
               PChar2 + 
               PChar3 +
               PChar4 +
               Age +
               PTestScore1 +
               PTestScore2 +
               CategoricalPatientVar +
               ItemDifficulty +
               (1|Item) +
               (1|ParticipantID))
```

Which returns warnings like (despite all variables scales/adjusted):

```
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 12.0686 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
 - Rescale variables?
3: Model failed to converge with 2 negative eigenvalues: -2.0e-02 -1.8e+09
```

and this error which renders the model impossible:

```
Error in eval_f(x, ...) : Downdated VtV is not positive definite
```

Comment: Why would you use the condition advantage (difference) as DV? How about putting condition (0,1) in one column, and accuracy in another column? That way, you can use accuracy as DV, and condition as another IV in your mixed model. The condition effect would be evaluated as the condition main effect.

Comment: Simply because we suspect something about the participants themselves may be conferring steeper performance differences between conditions. When you say accuracy as the DV, do you mean Accuracy (coded as 0 or 1)? I ran that as a logistic mixed-effect/glmer and fit/selected using a LASSO regression which seemed to produce plausible results/interpretation.

Comment: For differential effect of condition on accuracy (DV) depending on participant, you can use a random slope term to the condition effect to take care of that.

Comment: Thanks! I will check that approach out.

Comment: If the model without random slopes is failing to converge, then one with random slopes probably will too. Changing the optimizer may help with convergence issues. However, it's still a very complex model which suggests perhaps doing some analysis of parsimony. That is, though some recommend fitting a maximal model for random effects in experiments, sometimes it just doesn't converge if the model has too many variance components (which may be related to the identifiability error listed there). Good luck!